# invoke self function in hyperledger fabric written by node.js

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In hyperledger fabric, when i written chaincode by node.js.  how can i invoke anthor function by `invoke` ?

```
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
    var Chaincode = class {
        async Init(stub) {}
        async Invoke(stub) {}
        async func1(stub) {
            // how to invoke `func2` here?
        }
        async func2(stub) {}
    }
```

I want to invoke `func2` in `func1`.

Comment: Did you try
 this.func2()?

Comment: @LeonardoCarraro yes, but i got `undefined function`. I also move the `func2` function out of the class `Chaincode` as a global function. the same error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**V1**: Based on the official nodeJS fabcar chaincode example ([link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/chaincode/fabcar/node/fabcar.js)), this should work:

```
var Chaincode = class {
        async Invoke(){
            let method = this["func1"];
            await method(stub,this);
            //...
        }

        async func1(stub,methods) {
            await methods.func2(stub);
            //your code
        }

        async func2(stub) { 
            //your code 
        }
    }
```

**V2**: Normal Javascript class

```
var Chaincode = class{

    constructor(){

    }

    async func1(){
        console.log("FUNC 1");
        this.func2();
    }

    async func2(){
        console.log("FUNC 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: From you code and the way you testing, result is ok.  but in fabric, all function `invoke` is invoked by `fabric-shim` utils. so that can't testing directly by normally ways. chaincode should testing in hyperledger fabric environment.

Comment: It's true. Based on the official nodeJS fabcar chaincode 

(https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/chaincode/fabcar/node/fabcar.js)

maybe this could work:

`var Chaincode = class{
   
    async func1(stub) {
        let method = this["func2"];
        let res = await method(stub);
    }

    async func2(stub){
        //your code
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time since this question has been asked but for those who are facing the same issue, this is how I fixed it:

```
var Chaincode = class {
        constructor() {    
            this.func1 = this.func1.bind(this)
        }
        async Init(stub) {}
        async Invoke(stub) {}
        async func1(stub) {
            // how to invoke `func2` here?
            this.func2(stub)
        }
        async func2(stub) {}
    }
```